# Count alternating up / down sequences

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Description of the problem :
Compute the number of all the sequences which go up down from some input n.
So the user input n; with that n then I create an array of numbers 1..n and then number the sequences with that property

Example: `n = 4`

```
1 3 2 4
1 4 2 3
2 3 1 4
2 4 1 3
3 4 1 2
```

Answer: `5`

My program works but for some reason I sometimes get 0 instead of the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

void swap(int *fir, int *sec) {
    int temp = *fir;
    *fir = *sec;
    *sec = temp;
}

void permute(int *array, int i, int length, int *count) {
    if (length == 2) {
        *count = 1;
        return;
    }
    if (length == i) {
        int v = 0, flag = 1;
        while (v < length) {
            if (v % 2 == 0) {
                if (array[v] < array[v + 1]) {
                    v++;
                } else {
                    flag = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (v % 2 != 0) {
                if (array[v] > array[v + 1]) {
                    v++;
                } else {
                    flag = 0;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            /*
            int a;
            for (a = 0; a < length; a++)
                printf("%d", array[a]);
            printf("\n");
            */
            *count = *count + 1;
        }
    }
    int j = i;
    for (j = i; j < length; j++) {
        swap(array + i, array + j);
        permute(array, i + 1, length, count);
        swap(array + i, array + j);
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *arr = safeMalloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    permute(arr, 0, n, &count);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `which go up down ` - please explain what does that mean?

Comment: It's not clear what "go up down from some input `n`" means? Does it mean something like: a sequence `a_1 ... a_k a_{k+1} ... a_n` where `a_1 ... a_k` is sorted, then `a_{k+1} ... a_n` is sorted again, but `a_k > a_{k+1}`. Where do permutations come into play? Also, it's safe to just use plain old `malloc` instead of `safeMalloc`. It's unlikely you'll run out of memory and you'd sooner be OOM-killed than have `malloc` return NULL in most setups.

Comment: Look at the examples: 1<3>2<4. What I mean by up down is that the numbers which are on even positions will always be smaller than the odd ones next to them

Comment: If n=4 then the array a will be {a[0],a[1].a[2],a[3]}. With that in mind the idea is that I need to get all the permutations that contains the numbers from 1 to n without repetitions and with the constrain that a[0]<a[1]>a[2]<a[3].

Comment: Note that question requires number of such sequences but does not ask for generate these sequences explicitly. Have you thought about mathematical way to calculate this number. Perhaps, some kind of dynamic programming / table filling?

Comment: Not really. But the strange thing is that the program seems to work most of the time. But on other platforms sometimes the program outputs 0 instead of the real answer.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000111

Comment: Actually calculating and counting the permutations is only going to work for very small values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically generate all permutations of the array elements and count the valid ones.

Your code has a minor flaw:

- the loop `while (v < length) {` goes one step too far: you access `tab[v + 1]` so the loop should stop at `v < length - 1`. As currently coded, it has undefined behavior.

You can further simply the code:

- there should be no need to special case `length == 2`.
- `flag` useless as you always return when you clear it.
- `if (v % 2 != 0)` is redundant: `else` would suffice.

Here is a fixed and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

void swap(int *fir, int *sec) {
    int temp = *fir;
    *fir = *sec;
    *sec = temp;
}

void permutate(int *array, int i, int length, int *count) {
    if (i == length) {
        for (int v = 0; v < length - 1; v++) {
            if (v % 2 == 0) {
                if (array[v] >= array[v + 1]) {
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (array[v] <= array[v + 1]) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        *count = *count + 1;
    } else {
        for (int j = i; j < length; j++) {
            swap(array + i, array + j);
            permutate(array, i + 1, length, count);
            swap(array + i, array + j);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0) {
        int *arr = safeMalloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = i + 1;
        }
        int count = 0;
        permutate(arr, 0, n, &count);
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you call tab(n,k) the number of updown sequence of length n with k being the last number in your sequence, you can write a recursive formula and implement it like that:

```
int N = 5+1;
int** tab = new int*[N];
for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
    tab[n] = new int[N];
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        tab[n][k] = 0;
    }
}
tab[1][1] = 1;
for (int n = 2; n < N; n++) {
    for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                tab[n][k] += tab[n-1][j];
            }
        }
        else {
            for (int j = k; j < n; j++) {
                tab[n][k] += tab[n-1][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
int res = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    res += tab[N - 1][j];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without iterating through the permutations. Say you're trying to calculate f(n). Where can the new, high number go? It has to go in an 'up' position, which is an even position. You can have any valid sequence of odd length preceding it, and any valid sequence following it.

Let's say we're calculating f(n,k) where the highest val is in position k, zero indexed. This is zero for k even. For odd k we get:

f(n,k) = choose(n-1, k) * f(k) * f(n - k - 1)

To get f(n), sum f(n,k) over odd k < n.

We have to calculate the first few by hand.

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1
f(3) = f(3,1) = choose(2,1) * f(1) * f(1) = 2 * 1 *1 = 2
f(4) = f(4,1) + f(4,3) = choose(3,1) * f(1) * f(2) + choose(3,3) * f(3) * f(0) = 3*1*1 + 1*2*1 = 5
f(5) = f(5,1) + f(5,3) = choose(4,1) * f(1) * f(3) + choose(4,3) * f(3) * f(1) = 4*1*2 + 4*2*1 = 16
```